# Relationship between Blob object and its data

Tags: javascript, dom

Will the blob object be garbage collected when I use `createObjectURL` to get its url and subsequently do not hold any references to the `Blob` object? Or it won't be GCed before the url revoked?

```js
async function getImageBlobURL() {
  const res = await fetch('/image.png');
  const blob = await res.blob(); // will it be GCed?
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return url;
}

const img = document.createElement('img');
const url = await getImageBlobURL();
img.url = url;
document.body.append(img);
```

---

What I want to do is:

```js
const finalizationRegistry = new FinalizationRegistry<string>((url) => {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});

/**
 * Get the URL of the blob, which will automatically revoke as the blob is GCed.
 * Anyone using this url must also hold the blob reference.
 */
export function getAutoRevokableBlobUrl(blob: Blob) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  finalizationRegistry.register(blob, url);
  return url;
}

// how to use:
const img = document.createElement('img');
const url = getAutoRevokableBlobUrl(blob);
img.url = url;

// when the `img` removed and GCed, the `blob` can be GCed
// and the url will be automatically revoked in `finalizationRegistry`
img._blobObj = blob; 

document.body.append(img);
```

Comment: My guess is no, it won't be collected, as the URL points to the blob in memory. The blob is just some bytes in memory, the URL doesn't encode that because there is no better way to encode a blob than just a block/blob of memory. It would be highly inefficient to do otherwise.

Comment: Toward your underlying question: unless you're using a framework that offers cleanup functions when elements are removed (e.g. React's render cycles), then using the [`MutationObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) is probably the idiomatic approach to revoking blob URLs when certain elements are removed from the DOM.

Comment: It seems like you should simply put the finalisation on the `img` object not on the `blob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the Blob object be garbage collected when I use `createObjectURL` to get its URL and subsequently do not hold any references to the Blob object?

[No, it won't.](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#url-intro) When you call `URL.createObjectURL`, a mapping from the URL string to the Blob is added to the browser's internal "blob URL store". This mapping keeps the Blob alive until you call `URL.revokeObjectURL`.

Hence your `getAutoRevokableBlobUrl` function won't work.